# Testing locklessness C++

Tags: c++, real-time, lockless

Is there any way to detect whether a function or thread is blocking? I want to build a test case in which I can test whether a function is hard realtime-safe.

Comment: It appears that you're trying to solve the Halting Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  I can help you with that.  First, you simply

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no general way to do this.

There are many ways to 'block' such as a spin-lock and similar 'try-fail-retry' algorithms that there's no realistic way to instrument what code 'blocks'.

Look at something like a sequential lock. That's a lock that never blocks a (single) writer but causes readers to re-try if they make have made a read during a write (and so may have read a corrupt value).

It scales in readers really well particularly if writes are relatively infrequent. Certainly the important point being readers don't block each other so the delay on reads is a fixed value as readers scale.

It's debatable whether it's technically lock-free and surely impossible to write a tool to analyse the algorithm and determine if it is lock-free or at what point it is (logically) blocking.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  Consider this function:

```
unsigned compute(unsigned x)
{
    while (x < 10) {
        if (x) {
            x++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

It will run in bounded time, unless `x` is zero in which case it will take infinite time.

You cannot determine whether such functions exist in your program, because of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

If you only need to determine whether your program calls specific system functions that you have determined to be blocking, such as network I/O, you can do that by interposing (via `LD_PRELOAD`, `-fwrap` or similar linking tricks) wrapper functions around those restricted system functions.  For example you could write a wrapper for `recv()` which will check that the file descriptor is non-blocking, and return `EINVAL` otherwise.

Note that on many systems, disk I/O is fundamentally a blocking operation, so you'll need to disable that entirely.